# I deleted trusted software providers from authentication in software and updates

Tags: apt, updates, software-center, vmware

I am currently using ubuntu 14.04 LTS

I was getting a 404 error whenever I used `sudo apt-get update`.

I feel it is because of some trusted software providers which I deleted - ubuntu archive automatic signing key (2012) and another, that I've forgotten.

I thought these are added because of my mistakes and wrong commands while installing VMware.

After doing this I am getting errors in software updates. Is this because of what I just did?

here are all of the errors:

```
errors are Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
  404  Not Found
Ign archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US Fetched 1,069 kB in 51s (20.7 kB/s)

W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs: 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32

W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs: 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32 W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs: 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32

W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs: 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32

W: Failed to fetch ppa.launchpad.net/picaso/octave/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/… 404 –
```

Comment: We need to see the new error when you run the command `sudo apt-get update`. Please [edit] it in.

Comment: Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US                
Fetched 1,069 kB in 51s (20.7 kB/s)                                            
W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs:
3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs:
3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs:
3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs:
3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/picaso/octave/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404

Comment: these are some other errors

Comment: Please [edit] it in and format as code, by selecting and pressing Ctrl+K or clicking the `{}` button. Then you can have the whole thing in the code.

Comment: @Tim here we go

Comment: i dont have enough reputation for movig to conversation ...please tell me what about the trusted software providers i just deleted?

Comment: what do you need the rep for? Commenting there? I'm not sure about that, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can add Public Keys to your apt keychain using `apt-key`.  It is up to you to determine whether or not to trust the keys and import them.  Here is how you would do it:

1. `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 886DDD89 7F0CEB10 C300EE8C`

   - Where keys are separated by spaces.
   - You may use full keys, or the last eight characters, as show above.
   - This example would import Tor, NGINX and MongoDB keys.