# Software Updater doesn't ask for password

Tags: upgrade, updates, update-manager, system-settings

I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 from 15.10 a few weeks ago. After upgrade my Software Updater stopped asking for Administrator Authentication before installing new updates. It just shows that new updates are available and when I click on Update now, it starts updating without asking for password.

How can I set it to previous settings?

Comment: What you are seeing has been so since Ubuntu 11.10 and was already so in 15.10. See https://askubuntu.com/a/86785/15811

Comment: I don't know about previous releases because I started using Ubuntu with 15.10 release and it always used to ask for password.

Comment: I just updated Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop and was asked the provide Administrator Authentication. Could it depend on whether the update is coming from a source listed in the Trusted Software Providers list?

Comment: @sempaiscuba Which list are u talking about?

Comment: @RD017 The list is on the `Authentication` tab of `Software and Updates` in `System Settings`.

Comment: @sempaiscuba Yes, there are somethings in that list. Am I supposed to remove them?

Comment: @RD017 No. Absolutely **do not** remove them! See [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/627060/i-deleted-trusted-software-providers-from-authentication-in-software-and-updates)